# How do I set the file mask for find in path for [.ts,.tsx] not for [.d.ts]?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to use Find in Path for ts and tsx files in WebStorm, but it gives me .d.ts files I didn't need.

I tried to set `*.tsx,*(^.d).ts` in file mask, but it doesn't work.

`*.tsx,*.ts` ->  `.tsx`+`.ts`+`.d.ts`, `.d.ts` is not needed

`*.tsx,*(^.d).ts` -> doesn't work

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `!` at the start of the file name part for negating, e.g. try the following: `!*.d.ts,*.tsx,*.ts`

---

Here is me searching in `.php` file but ignoring `.d.php` -- `!*.d.php,*.php` (I've simply used `.php` file instead of `.js` in my experiment).

As you may see it finds all 3 results:
[image]

With that mask enabled the IDE finds only 2 files:
[image]

---

Another approach is to make a Custom Scope that will include files with desired file extensions and then selecting it when doing a search.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html